# Deque removing elements from front and putting them to the back

Tags: c++, deque

I have a deque object of type int with a lot of elements and my task is to get all elements from the first halve of the queue and put them at the back and remove these elements from the front :for example [1,2,3,4,5] will become [3,4,5,1,2].
Currently the code that does this is :

```
for(int i=0;i<myDeque.size()/2;i++)
{
        int a=myDeque.front();
        myDeque.pop_front();
        myDeque.push_back(a);
}
```

Is there a way to optimize this process?

Comment: See [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) which already does this.

Comment: Yes, you should be swapping the elements, rather than moving them around.

Comment: I just tried with rotate and it didn't achieve my goal to be under 2 seconds ,I have tested in on deque with 900,000 elements and use rotate like this : std::rotate(result.rbegin(), result.rbegin() + 1, result.rend());

Comment: @Gordon That function call will rotate the entire deque by a single position. Are you calling that in a loop? You can do the "rotation by half" with a single call to rotate().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use std::rotate like this:

```
   std::rotate( myDeque.begin(), myDeque.begin() + dequeSize/2, myDeque.end());
```

Complete test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm> // std::rotate


void printDequeBegin(const std::deque<int>& aDeque)
{
   auto d {aDeque.cbegin()};
   auto i {0};
   while (i < 10 && d != aDeque.cend())
   {
      std::cout << *d++ << " ";
      ++i; 
   }
   std::cout << "\n";
}


int main()
{

   const int dequeSize { 9000000 };
   std::deque<int> myDeque;

   for (int i = 0; i < dequeSize; )
   {
      myDeque.push_back(++i);
   }

   printDequeBegin(myDeque);

   auto start {std::chrono::system_clock::now()};

   std::rotate( myDeque.begin(), myDeque.begin() + dequeSize/2, myDeque.end()); 

   auto end {std::chrono::system_clock::now()};

   auto ms {std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end-start)};
   std::cout << ms.count() << " ms\n";

   printDequeBegin(myDeque);

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
326 ms
4500001 4500002 4500003 4500004 4500005 4500006 4500007 4500008 4500009 4500010
```